# cannot install in a container dotnet sdk 6.0 and jdk 8

Tags: c#, .net, java-8, sdk, dockerfile

I need to install in the same container dotnet sdk 6.0 and jdk 8, I am implemented the following dockerfile but creates the container and when reviewing java this does not appear installed

##Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS build-jdk
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
COPY --from=build-jdk ./* ./
COPY . .
# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline        
ENV JAVA_HOME /app/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DigitalSignature.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "DigitalSignature.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DigitalSignature.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DigitalSignature.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DigitalSignature.dll"]
```

The container is created but when checking if java is installed, it does not appear

commands

```
java -version
Java -version 
printenv | env
```

[checking java and environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNBzj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the next Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
# Install "software-properties-common" (for the "add-apt-repository")
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common

## Install Oracle's JDK
# add oracle jdk repository
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa && \
# accept oracle license
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set- 
selections && \
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set- 
selections && \
    apt-get update && \
# install oracle jdk 8 and make it default


apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer && \
  apt-get -y install oracle-java8-set-default && \
# clean up
  apt-get clean all && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*   

 Run wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
     dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
     rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

 Run apt-get update; \
     apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
     apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0

Run apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DigitalSignature.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "DigitalSignature.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DigitalSignature.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DigitalSignature.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DigitalSignature.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're copying and configuring Java in the `build` stage of the Dockerfile (`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build`) but that stage is only used to build your .NET project. That stage is not used in the file image. So anything that's not explicitly copied from that stage into the final stage essentially gets thrown out.

I would suggest moving your commands that install/configure Java up to the initial stage of the Dockerfile, the one labeled `base`. The `final` stage is based on `base` so anything included in their will be available in your image.

Having it in the `base` stage will allow it to be available when using the "fast debug" container feature in Visual Studio too.

Comment: the environment variables are created and I see that everything is installed but java does not run, then the image of the container files is shown, on the left that java does not work and on the right a container only with java https://prnt.sc/nQ8bholZUNJu